# How to kill running exec task in ANT

Tags: ant, continuous-integration, weblogic-10.x, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to start a weblogic server using ant exec command,after the operation triggers the exec process creates a child process, i wish to kill the parent process and keep alive the child process.

My code below

```
<project name="startserver" default="start" basedir=".">
        <target name="start">
            <exec dir="C:\bea\user_projects\domains\devtest" 
                     executable="cmd" 
                     failonerror="true">
                     <arg value="/c"/>
                 <arg value="startWebLogic.cmd"/>
             </exec>
        </target>
</project>
```

this code starts server and my application is also up, problem is that ant script is still running & moreover it doesn't exit as shown below

[image]

how can i exit from the exec and kill the parent process, as a workaround i tried using

> timeout

attribute of exec task, but it kills both parent and child process, how can i achieve this so that ANT exits and also server keeps running in the background.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `spawn="true"` attribute of the [`exec`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task. It should do what you are looking for. But beware of the implications for input/output handling (see link).

Comment: i could not achieve even after using spawn="true"

Answer (score 0):

When you set `spawn="true"` for `exec` tag, the child process runs in the the background even if current process ends execution. In your case instead of `cmd`, use `startweblogic.cmd` directly as `exec` command.